# Is ensemble learning a subset of meta learning?

Tags: ensemble-modeling, meta-learning

I'm studying ensemble learning methods, focusing on random forest and gradient boost. I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) article about this topic and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_learning_(computer_science)) about meta-learning. It is possible to say that ensemble learning is a subset of meta-learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Meta-learning**, also known as "learning to learn", is a subset of machine learning It is used to improve the results and performance of a learning algorithm by changing some aspects of the learning algorithm based on experiment results. **Meta-learning** helps researchers understand which algorithm(s) generate the best/better predictions from datasets.

**Meta-learning** algorithms use metadata of learning algorithms as input. Then, they make predictions and provide information about the performance of these learning algorithms as output.

From [What Is Meta-Learning in Machine Learning?](https://machinelearningmastery.com/meta-learning-in-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=More%20generally%2C%20meta%2Dmodels%20for,as%20a%20meta%2Dlearning%20algorithm.)

> More generally, **meta-models for supervised learning** are almost always **ensemble learning algorithms**, and any **ensemble learning algorithm** that uses another model to combine the predictions from ensemble members may be referred to as a **meta-learning algorithm**.